# Sql syntax error

Tags: posts, errors, sql

Sometimes in my error log i have this error:

> ```
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to 
> use near '' at line 1    
>     SELECT * 
>     FROM c_posts 
>     WHERE id = , 
>     do_action('wp_ajax_inline-save'), 
>     call_user_func_array, 
>     wp_ajax_inline_save, 
>     edit_post, 
>     wp_update_post, 
>     wp_insert_post, 
>     wp_transition_post_status, 
>     do_action('transition_post_status'), 
>     call_user_func_array, 
>     apt_check_required_transition, 
>     apt_publish_post, 
>     W3_Db->query
> ```

How to fix this ?

I think error in this plugin. It is piece of code :

```
/**
  * Function to check whether scheduled post is being published. If so, apt_publish_post should be called.
  *
  * @param $new_status
  * @param $old_status
  * @param $post
  * @return void
  */
 function apt_check_required_transition($new_status='', $old_status='', $post='') {
global $post_ID; // Using the post id from global reference since it is not available       in $post object. Strange!

if ('publish' == $new_status) {
    apt_publish_post($post_ID);
}
 }

 /**
 * Function to save first image in post as post thumbmail.
 */
 function apt_publish_post($post_id)
  {
global $wpdb;

// First check whether Post Thumbnail is already set for this post.
if (get_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', true) || get_post_meta($post_id, 'skip_post_thumb', true)) {
    return;
}

$post = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE id = $post_id");

// Initialize variable used to store list of matched images as per provided regular expression
$matches = array();

// Get all images from post's body
preg_match_all('/<\s*img [^\>]*src\s*=\s*[\""\']?([^\""\'>]*)/i', $post[0]->post_content, $matches);

if (count($matches)) {
    foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $image) {
        /**
         * If the image is from wordpress's own media gallery, then it appends the thumbmail id to a css class.
         * Look for this id in the IMG tag.
         */
        preg_match('/wp-image-([\d]*)/i', $image, $thumb_id);
        $thumb_id = $thumb_id[1];

        // If thumb id is not found, try to look for the image in DB. Thanks to "Erwin Vrolijk" for providing this code.
        if (!$thumb_id) {
            $image = substr($image, strpos($image, '"')+1);
            $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE guid = '".$image."'");
            $thumb_id = $result[0]->ID;
        }

        // Ok. Still no id found. Some other way used to insert the image in post. Now we must fetch the image from URL and do the needful.
        if (!$thumb_id) {
            $thumb_id = apt_generate_post_thumb($matches, $key, $post[0]->post_content, $post_id);
        }

        // If we succeed in generating thumg, let's update post meta
        if ($thumb_id) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $thumb_id );
            break;
        }
    }
}
 }// end apt_publish_post()
```

Comment: Check where you got `do_action('wp_ajax_inline-save')` ... and check where the `W3_Db` class comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error in the SQL statement is at the very end,

```
SELECT * 
FROM c_posts 
WHERE id = ,
```

There is no value being supplied to check against the `id` column. This is most likely because you didn't check for a blank value in the ID field before forming and executing the query. Check the code in the function `apt_publish_post` to ensure that the value being inserted into the query for `id` is non-empty and a positive integer.

**Update**

Now that you've provided the code for `apt_publish_post`, it is clear why this could be happening.

- `apt_check_required_transition` is hooked on the `transition_post_status` action, which accepts three arguments, $old_status, $new_status, and $post. If registered correctly with [`add_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action), all three variables are guaranteed to be defined.

  `add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'apt_check_required_transition', 10, 3);`

  - It's important that the last two arguments to add_action are provided: `$priority` and `$num_arguments;` here I have `$priority = 10` and `$num_arguments = 3`, to correspond to the number of arguments the `transition_post_status` action supplies.
- `apt_check_required_transition` thus will accept a `$post` object as the third argument, whose ID `$post->ID` should be passed to apt_publish_post
- `apt_publish_post` should do some basic sanity checks on its argument, `$post_id`:

  `if( ( $post_id = (int) $post_id ) < 1 ) 
      return;`

  - This is just one of a whole variety of ways in PHP to check for type and domain validity.
- Always use `$wpdb->prepare()` when creating SQL statements. This adds another layer of protection against injection attacks.

  `$post = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE id = %d", $post_id ) );`

  - Despite this, the `get_post()` WordPress API function is a much better way to obtain a post object given a post ID:

  `$post = get_post( $post_id );`

  - This differs from your current method in that you get a single post, rather than an array of posts as you do using `$wpdb->get_results()`
- You could also just pass the $post object provided to `apt_check_required_transition` directly to `apt_publish_post` rather than getting its ID and then looking it up again. This would eliminate the need for sanity checks, as $post would always be defined in this situation.

Comment: Thank you Ben. I edidet my question and found needed codes. How to fix error ?